Not able to ping Gateway Subnet in Azure
Need some help i am not able to ping my gateway subnet from my Azure VM. Currently i am using 1 vnet and has 3 subnets.

AzureBastionSubnet
Gateway Subnet - which is connected with VPN Gateway has it own IP address space of 172.16.201.0/25
Default subnet - used by my VM.

enter image description here
enter image description here
Based on some of the documentation from Microsoft i checked my routing table and everything is allowed and then i checked ICMP firewall which is also allowed inside my Azure VM. But still when i am trying to ping it doesnt connect.
enter image description here
Here is my NSG settings.
enter image description here
So I am not sure what else i can check to ping between my default subnet and Gateway Subnet. Any inputs?
Tried enabling ICMP traffic on VM.
Tried adding routing rules on route table but still no luck.
then enabling IPforwarding key to 1 in registry: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
